# What is the force escaping gas exerts on its container?

Tags: thermodynamics

There is a simple problem that I met today, one that I couldn't find a solution for that I was satisfied with.

Assuming we have a tank filled with gas at a certain pressure $p$ and temperature $T$, with the molecules of the gas having the mass $m$. There is a hole on the side of the tank where the pressurized gas escapes into vacuum.

I believe that the force would then be calculated using $$F=\dot m \cdot v_{th}$$ with $v_{th}$ being the [thermal velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_velocity) $$v_{th}=\sqrt{\frac {8k_BT}{m\pi}}.$$

I would further assume that $\dot m$ is directly proportional to the pressure of the tank, however I don't know any equation I'd be able to substitute it for.

Is this right so far, or am I making completely false assumptions here? What would the final equation for $F$ look like?

Comment: Is this the exact statement of the problem?  What force F are you trying to determine (the force to expel the gas, the force the gas exerts on the tank, other)?

Comment: Wouldn't those two forces be the same? If anything, what I'd be looking for is the force the escaping gas exerts on the tank. The contextual problem is the question of what the force would be if using escaping gas as a propellant. I've edited the qestion to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chester Miller points out that my simplistic answer is incorrect. Please see his derivation in the comment section below.

Comment: Well, seems like I was totally overthinking it. Thanks for this answer, it's very simple to understand.

Comment: thanks for that. on a related topic, you should see my answer to the question of how to determine the mass of the earth's atmosphere. I did it in a single line of algebra and got to within 5% of the published value, and scored exactly zero points for it!

Comment: in my judgment, this answer is not correct, because the gas is being accelerated out of the hole.  A combination of the Bernoulli equation together with the macroscopic momentum balance on the gas shows that the force is actually 2x the tank pressure times the area.

Comment: I will delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The force would be simply the product between the pressure and the surface of the hole in the tank, say $F = PS_h$, where $F$ is the force, $P$ is the pressure and $S_h$ the surface of the hole. But the force is changing in time, than it's interesting to see how the force is varying with time.
A solution might be this one:

Gas molecules are hitting the tank surface right? What is the chance of escaping the tank assuming a single molecule is hitting the surface? I'd say

$P_e = S_h/S$

where S is the total surface of the tank.
Then, what is the average time $\Delta t$ in which a collision with the surface occurs? Given the thermal velocity (which is constant! it is a function of the mass of the molecule which does not change in time, and the temperature that is fixed as well), we can compute this time from the second principle of dynamics.

$F_p = \frac{\Delta p}{\Delta t}$, where $F_p$ is the force that a single particle applies to the surface of the tank, $\Delta p$ is the variation of momentum, and $\Delta t$ the time interval.
$F_p = PS/N$, where N is the number of particle.$\mid\Delta p\mid = 2mv_{th}$ because the particle is bouncing back at the same velocity.

So we get

$\Delta t = \frac{2Nmv_{th}}{PS}$.

Now, I'm sorry if it is messy, the 'getting stuck' probability when the particle hits the surface several times, say $N_h$, is

$P_g(N_h) = (1-P_e)^{N_h}$.

How many collision happen during the time interval t? $N_h = t/{\Delta t}$!
Then the mass in the tank should be proportional to this probability, that decreases with time.
The mass in the tank is also proportional to the pressure, so, lastly, we can write the pressure as a function of time as

$P(t) = P(0)(1-S_h/S)^{\frac{t}{\Delta t}}$,

where $P(0)$ is the initial pressure.

Let me know what you think about this solution.